# cordova-plugin-local-notifications click event after app is killed

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I found a lot of old treads on this but I didn't find a clear answer to make the local notifications click event work after the app was killed. The notifications work if the app is active or in the background. To test I wrote the following code.

```
app.initEvents = function() {
    "use strict" ;
    var fName = "app.initEvents():" ;
    app.consoleLog(fName, "entry") ;


    cordova.plugins.notification.local.isPresent(1, function (present) 
    {
        if (! present) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 2);
            cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: "Test message",
                message: "Message body",
                date: d
            });
        }
    });

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification, state) {
        alert(notification.id + " was clicked -> app.Ready");
    }, this);

    var el, evt ;

    if( navigator.msPointerEnabled || !('ontouchend' in window))
        evt = "click" ;
    else
        evt = "touchend" ;

    app.hideSplashScreen() ;

    app.consoleLog(fName, "exit") ;
} ;
document.addEventListener("app.Ready", app.initEvents, false) ;
```

What happens is that the notification is scheduled and is shown after 2 minutes. If the app is killed in the mean time the notification is still triggered but the click event is not handled and the notification is scheduled again. So I assume the notification is cleared after it was clicked and because the app.ready event gets handled later it cannot handle the click event?

Is there a way to make this work? I'm using CLI 6.5 and version 0.8.4 of the plugin. I only tested on Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Did you find the solution on the above case?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure, the event listener will fire, you have to place it inside `deviceready` e.g.:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

const onDeviceReady = () => {
  window.cordova.plugins.notification.local.on('click', (notification, args) => {
      alert(notification.id + " was clicked -> app.Ready");
  });
}
```

Make sure, however to place it right after the `deviceready` is called, otherwise, it might not work properly.